# SQL Server : select distinct until the value is changed

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of tasks (each task can has a few rows) that looks something like this:

```
TaskID | DateCreated | Status
-------+-------------+------------
  1    | 01-01-2017  | Started
  2    | 02-02-2017  | InProgress
  1    | 02-02-2017  | Started
  1    | 03-03-2017  | InProgress
  2    | 03-03-2017  | InProgress
  1    | 04-04-2017  | InProgress
  2    | 04-04-2017  | Done
  1    | 05-05-2017  | Done
```

I have more columns which are not relevant for this requirement.

What I need here is to select the actual status flow that a specific task has passed.

For example, for task with TaskID = 1, I want to get the following result:

```
TaskID | Status
-------+-------------
  1    | Started
  1    | InProgress
  1    | Done
```

**Notes:**

1. The rows may be not sorted
2. A status can repeat itself, e.g. there can be a task that its' status flow was:

   ```
   Started ==> InProgress ==> Break ==> InProgress ==> Done
   ```

   so will not help me to get for each task the unique status from each status type it passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL 2012+ you could use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)

```
  DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
  (
    TaskID int,
    DateCreated date,
    Status varchar(20)
  )

  INSERT INTO @SampleData
  VALUES
  (1, '2017-01-01', 'Started'),
  (2, '2017-02-02', 'InProgress'),
  (1, '2017-02-02', 'Started'),
  (1, '2017-03-03', 'InProgress'),
  (2, '2017-03-03', 'InProgress'),
  (1, '2017-04-04', 'InProgress'),
  (2, '2017-04-04', 'Done'),
  (1, '2017-05-05', 'Done')

  ;with temp as
  (
     SELECT  *, 
             lag(sd.Status,1,'') OVER(PARTITION BY sd.TaskID ORDER BY sd.DateCreated)  AS PreviousRowStatus 
     FROM @SampleData sd
  )
  SELECT t.TaskID, t.DateCreated, t.Status
  FROM temp t
  WHERE t.Status != t.PreviousRowStatus
  ORDER BY t.TaskID
```

Returns

```
TaskID  DateCreated Status
--------------------------
1       2017-01-01  Started
1       2017-03-03  InProgress
1       2017-05-05  Done
2       2017-02-02  InProgress
2       2017-04-04  Done
```

For older version you could use `Row_number` and `APPLY`

Answer (score 1):

Below is the query where in partition by will fetch you the desired result.

```
select taskid,status(select taskid,status
,row_number()over(partition by taskid,status order by taskid)rownum
from [yourtablename])tmp
where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Query (select distinct ):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TaskID, Status
FROM            (SELECT   TaskID, Status
                          FROM            task
                          ORDER BY TaskID) AS task_1
WHERE        (TaskID = 1)
ORDER BY Status DESC
```

Or Simply :

```
SELECT DISTINCT TaskID, Status
FROM            task
WHERE        (TaskID = 1)
ORDER BY TaskID, Status DESC
```

Result for your demo content:

[image]