# SQL Show the previous value until the given value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table ordered by **ID** with column **Value**.

```
| ID       | Value          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 50             |
| 2        | 50             |
| 3        | 62             |
| 4        | 62             |
| 5        | 62             |
| 6        | 79             |
| 7        | 90             |
| 8        | 90             |
```

I would like to create another column **Prev_Value** that for each row of column **Value** takes the previous/preceding number that differs from the current row value, as in the table below.

Output table:

```
| ID       | Value          |Prev_Value     |
| -------- | -------------- |---------------|
| 1        | 50             |NULL           |
| 2        | 50             |NULL           |
| 3        | 62             |50             |
| 4        | 62             |50             |
| 5        | 62             |50             |
| 6        | 79             |62             |
| 7        | 90             |79             |
| 8        | 90             |79             |
```

Should I use modified LAG() function, the CROSS APPLY or nested CASE and what approach would be the most time-efficient? Any help would be appreciated.

Here are some references that unfortunately does not solve my problem:
[LAG(offset) until value is reached in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146015/lagoffset-until-value-is-reached-in-bigquery) and
[SQL Server : select distinct until the value is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381793/sql-server-select-distinct-until-the-value-is-changed)

Comment: Are the values always increasing?

Comment: No, they could decrease as well. I should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: . . That would have made it marginally easier using a cumulative maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses `apply`:

```
select t.*, tprev.value
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.value <> t.value and
            tprev.id < t.id
      order by tprev.id desc
     ) tprev;
```

The above is not the most efficient method on a large dataset.  For that, I would suggest getting the first time that a value changes and marking that.

```
select t.*,
        max(case when prev_value <> value then prev_value end) over (partition by grp) as prev_value
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_value = value then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(value) over (order by id) as prev_value
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a488bf881df9f9fc6b60f5ccb6c2bb91) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. (Check it live on [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f5eb6/8))

```
 select 
    t1.*, 
    t2.value prev_value  
from 
    t t1 
    left join t t2 on t2.id = (select max(id) from t where value<t1.value)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the "Value" column could have lower numbers in the following rows with higher id eg. (ID, Value) (8, 92) (9, 75)